# Deleting a self-referencing @ManyToMany connection

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have a self-referencing entity `Product`:

```
<?php
/** @Entity @Table(name="products") **/
class Product
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
    protected $id;
    /** @Column(type="string", nullable=true) **/
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="connectedBy", cascade={"all"})
     */
    protected $connectedWith;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="connectedWith", cascade={"all"})
     * @JoinTable(name="connection",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="connected_product_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    protected $connectedBy;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connectedWith = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->connectedBy = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
    public function getConnected()
    {
        return $this->connectedWith;
    }

    public function addConnection(Product $product)
    {
        $this->connectedWith->add($product);
        $product->connectedBy->add($this);
    }

    public function removeConnection(Product $product)
    {
        $this->connectedBy->removeElement($product);
        $this->connectedWith->removeElement($product);
    }
}
```

Next I created two products (IDs 1 and 2) and a connection between the both products:

```
mysql> select * from products;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | NULL |
|  2 | NULL |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from connection;
+------------+----------------------+
| product_id | connected_product_id |
+------------+----------------------+
|          2 |                    1 |
+------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Now I want to remove the connection with this code:

```
$product1 = $entityManager->find('Product', 1);
$product2 = $entityManager->find('Product', 2);
$product1->removeConnection($product2);
$entityManager->persist($product1);
$entityManager->flush();

$product3 = $entityManager->find('Product', 1);
print count($product3->getConnected()) . "\n";
```

As expected, the code prints `0` as its result. But when I look into the database, the connection entry still exists. What could be the cause any how could this be fixed?

I've already tried to `$entityManager->persist($product2)` but to no avail.

Comment: Do you try to delete the relation in the other way ? With $product2->removeConnection($product1);

Comment: It's funny but yes - that works! @UgoT. Can you imagine why?

Comment: Because it is a bi-directionnal relationship. With ManyToMany you have to do so. However, i don't know if it exists a way to automatically remove all the relationships (like an annotation or something like that...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I researched a little more and found the solution myself:

My function `removeConnection()` has a bug: I removed the product from both lists, `connectedBy` and `connectedWith`, which is wrong. Instead, I should do it like in `addConnection()`:

```
$this->connectedWith->removeElement($product);
$product->connectedBy->removeElement($this);
```